# python getting local time zone?

Tags: amazon-web-services, datetime, lambda, timezone

I'm using tzlocal.get_localzone() to get the local time zone.  However, on AWS Lambda this returns "local" instead of the actual TZ such as "Americas/New_York" I'm then trying to use the return value with datetime.replace(tzinfo=new_time_zone) however, this fails when passed in as "local"

Does anyone have a trick on how to do this in AWS so my lambda ftn uses the TZ relative to the region its running in, or do I need to escalate this with AWS?

Comment: The servers under Lambda (correctly) have no concept of their physical location's time zone.

Answer (score 4):

You should not use `tzlocal` in server-side code.  It is meant for desktop applications only.

- Most servers, especially in cloud-based services, set their system time zone to UTC.
- You have no *guarantee* that the server's time zone is set to anything in particular (including UTC, or a regional time zone).
- Your code should not behave differently when running from one cloud environment to the next, or on premises.

This is also described in [the timezone best practices article](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2532729/634824).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get the server's timezone name.  Meaning, if the server is located in Denver, Colorado, `TIME_ZONE` will be set to `"America/Denver"`.

```
import tzlocal
TIME_ZONE = tzlocal.get_localzone().zone
```